# Add labels to each subplots created using facet_wrap (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am quite new to ggplot2 (and R) so bear with me. Using `facet_wrap`, I have created a multi-panel plot. I want to label them with alphabetical letters (starting with the top-left panel labelled with (A), and the next panel with (b) and so on.) but I am not sure how to go about doing this. I want this to be located outside of the plot (ideally at the top left of each panel).

I came across `grid.text` and `ggtitle`, but I am not sure how I would implement these to get the desired outcome.

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690626/cant-label-multi-panel-figure-in-r-while-using-ggplot) and with the given answers it seems possible to manually label each figure, but I would like the labelling to be done automatically, in order.

I would deeply appreciate any advice/guides.

Comment: Where is the reproducible example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
p <- qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg) + facet_wrap(~ cyl) + 
    theme(panel.margin=unit(1,"line"))

library(gtable)
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
strips <- g$layout[grep("strip_t", g$layout$name), ]
titles <- lapply(paste0("(", letters[seq_len(nrow(strips))], ")"), 
                 textGrob, x = 0, hjust = 0, vjust = 1)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, grobs = titles, 
                     t = strips$t, b = strips$b - 2, 
                     l = strips$l, r = strips$r)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The 'grob' is so new to me so I had to get around to learn more about it. One question though. How to I fine-tune the position of the labels? I would like something in between "strips$b-1" and "strips$b-2". Thanks you!

Comment: you probably want to play with vjust in textGrob, between 0 and 1

Comment: Thanks. Because my original intention was to make the labels and the plots feel less crammed, I tried widening the strip size and it looks better (in my opinion). But I will play around with textGrob too. Thanks again!